# Proof that the least number of steps to some value $i$ if you can only travel in increasing powers of 2, is never done by overshooting $2i$

Tags: proof-explanation, algorithms, dynamic-programming

**The problem:**

This question is inspired by a proof of correctness for the algorithms question that can be found [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/race-car)

To summarize, starting from $0$, you want to get to some target $i > 0$.

You may only travel in increasing powers of two. For instance, starting from 0, you could do:
$0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 15...$

In other words, you can travel any distance $2^m -1, \quad m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

At any point, you may reverse and similarly travel a distance $2^n -1$ in the opposite direction.

You may do this as many times as you want until you get to the target $i$, and the goal is to get to $i$ in the least number of "steps". Reversing your direction counts against you as a step.

**The question:**

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but there is a detail in a supposedly valid algorithm (in fact, in many supposedly valid algorithms) that is often taken for granted, and which I have been unable to prove.

One such algorithm is a breadth first search algorithm, which simply looks at every possible position on the number line you could be after 1 step, 2 steps, 3 steps, and so on, until you get to $i$. This is wildly inefficient, so to speed this up, a trick is used that you only need to search within the interval $[0, 2i]$. That is, if you ever find yourself outside this interval, you can immediately give up searching any further down this branch.

I understand why you would never want to find yourself at some value on the number line $j < 0$, because you would eventually have to find a way to traverse a positive distance of $i + j$. However, you could have simply traversed a distance $i+j$ first, and then backtracked a distance $j$ to arrive at $i$, hence never having to find yourself at $j < 0$.

However, the detail which I am unable to prove is that you would never want to find yourself past the bound $2i$. I tried for a while to come up with possible counterexamples where the optimal path to $i$ was to first traverse to some $j > 2i$, and then backtrack to $i$, but I cannot find any counterexamples of this. I believe that this detail should intuitively be true, but I could not find a satisfying proof of this detail. Most people who "prove" the correctness of this detail simply say something along the lines of "well you would have to backtrack a distance $k := j - i  > i$, and traversing any distance $k > i$ would have to take more steps."

However, I can immediately show that this is not true, because if we suppose that $k = 7$ and $i = 6$, then we could get to $k$ in 3 steps ($0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 7$), while we would get to $i$ in 5 steps ($0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 6$) (because that reversing takes a step). So it is certainly possible to traverse greater distances in less steps, so why would we not travel past $2i$?

I hope that made sense and I hope this is the correct place to ask this question. This detail struck me as something that had to be proven algebraically which is why I came here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We want to get to $i$ and you ask

> So it is certainly possible to traverse greater distances in less steps, so why would we not travel past $2i$?

Between $i$ and $2i$, if you have a $2^j - 1$ for some $j$, you can reach $2^j-1$ in fewer steps than getting to $2i+\delta$. If you reach $2^j-1$ then you can reverse to reach $i$ in fewer steps than reversing from $2i + \delta$ to $i$.

If there is a power of $2$, say $2^j$ satisfying $i \lt 2^j \le 2i$ then $i \le 2^j - 1 \lt 2i$.

See [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/63202) for proof that there is a power of $2$ between $i$ and $2i$. In essence, write $2i$ in binary and replace all digits with $0$s after the leading $1$. That is a power of $2$ between $i$ and $2i$

That is because any position of the form $2^j - 1$ can be reached in $j+1$ steps using the sequence $1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow (2^{j-1} - 1) \rightarrow (2^j - 1)$.

Let $i$ satisfy the inequality

$$\overbrace{(2^{j-1} - 1)}^{A} \lt i \lt \overbrace{(2^j - 1)}^B \lt 2i < \overbrace{(2i + \delta)}^{C} < \overbrace{(2^{j+1}-1)}^{D}$$

Let it take $A_i$ steps to get to $i$ through $A$ following the path taken so far. Similarly let it take $B_i$ steps to get to $i$ through $B$ with a reversal. There are three possibilities:

- $A_i < B_i$
- $A_i = B_i$
- $A_i \gt B_i$

In each of these possibilities, we did not have to go beyond $2i$.

Now, replace $A,B,D$ with general integers you might reach if you continued down the path that you have taken so far where the inequality

$$A < i < B < 2i < \overbrace{(2i + \delta)}^{C} < D$$

holds i.e., $A, B, D$ are not of the form $2^\lambda - 1$. You can use the same argument as before to see that we don't need to go beyond $2i$.

Comment: I agree with what you say about being able to reach $2^j-1$ in fewer steps than $2i+\delta$, and I can see why there will be a power of 2 between $i$ and $2i$. However, the main detail that I fail to understand is the claim that if you reach $2^j-1$, then you can reverse to reach $i$ in fewer steps that reversing from $2i+\delta$ to $i$. Again, this is the step that seems intuitively clear because you are traversing less distance if you go from $2^j-1$ to $i$, but as I have shown before you can traverse larger distances in less steps, so how can we prove this is not the case for $2i + \delta$?

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the update, however I still fail to see why this proves the claim? It is true that we did not have to go beyond $2i$, but from my understanding, all this shows is that there exists a path to $i$ without going beyond $2i$, but not that such a path is optimal/shortest. That is, even though we may be able to construct a path to $i$ without going beyond $2i$, how do we show that this is indeed faster than any path that we do allow to go beyond $2i$? Thank you

Comment: Your question was specifically about why the optimal path does not require going beyond $2i$. We just showed that there are two paths requiring $A_i$ or $B_i$ steps that are both shorter than a path that goes beyond $2i$ (to $2i + \delta$) and then reverses. The optimal path has to be either $A_i$ steps or $B_i$ steps and that precludes going beyond $2i$. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In your example of $k = 7$ (current position) and target $i = 6$, the question you are asking is why a path that goes beyond $2i = 12$ and reverses is not optimal. You have $$(3 = 2^2 - 1)<(i=6) < (k=2^3 - 1=7) < (2i = 12) < (2^4 - 1 = 15)$$ From $7$ you can get to $6$, but you don't need to go beyond $12$ and then reverse from there.